# Android HTTP POST connection to file with response

Tags: android, http-get, apache-httpclient-4.x

How do I send the data to this PHP file below? I can establish the connection and send data, but can't receive the response. I need to send 3 parameters, the "op", Username and password.

```
switch ($_POST["op"]) {

    // User Authentication.
    case 1:
        $UName = $_POST["UName"];
        $UPass = $_POST["UPass"];
        $UPass = md5($UPass);

        //....Some code

    // New user registration process.
    case 2:
        $UName = $_POST["UName"];
        $UPass = $_POST["UPass"];
        $UEmail = $_POST["UEmail"];
        $UNick = $_POST["UNick"];
        $UPass = md5($UPass);

         //....Some code
        }
```

My code so far:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://SomeUrl/login.php");

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("1", "dan"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d(TAG, ""+responseBody);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your PHP code, at a bare minimum you need to specify an `op` parameter. Then depending on which op you're trying to carry out, make sure you specify the other needed parameters as well. For user authentication (op = 1):

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op", "1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UName", "dan"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pass", "somepass"));
```

On a side note, you should secure the PHP service with SSL, if you are using it to process sensitive user information.

Answer (score 1):

Android HTTP POST should look like this:

```
     HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

     // Data to send
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UName", "dan"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UPass", "password"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op", "1"));

     //http post
     try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://SomeUrl/login.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();

     }catch(Exception e){

     }
```

In your PHP code I would strongly recommend to use  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UName']) otherwise it is easy to attack via SQL injection.
I would also recommend to use either SSL connection (HTTPS) or to send the password only hashed (MD5)